# Angular inject $state service in config to redirect to a state in an interceptor

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, restangular, inject

I am using restangular and I have an interceptor. The idea is that for every response 401 the interceptor should redirect to a different state.

The problem is that angular does not allow the injection of services in config. It only allows the injection of providers.

**How can I have access to the `$state: ng.ui.IStateService` in my restangular interceptor?**

I know I could inject the provider `$stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider` but I don't think there is any way to navigate to certain state from the provider.

This is what I have:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/globals/restangular/index.d.ts" />

((): void => {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app")
        .config(configRestangular);

    configRestangular.$inject = [
        "$state",
        "RestangularProvider",
        "authSettings",
        "stateNames",
        "apiUrl"
    ];

    function isCustomValidationErrorResponse(response: restangular.IResponse) {
        return (response.data && response.data.customValidationError === true);
    }

    function configRestangular(
        $state: ng.ui.IStateService,
        restangularProvider: restangular.IProvider,
        authSettings: IAuthSettings,
        stateNames: IStateNames,
        apiUrl: string) {

        // restangular settings
        restangularProvider.setBaseUrl(apiUrl);

        restangularProvider.setErrorInterceptor((response: restangular.IResponse, deferred: ng.IDeferred<any>) => {
            if (response.status === 401) {
                $state.go(stateNames.login); //this will fail because $state cannot be injected here and I don't know how to navigate to a different state from $stateProvider
            } 
            return true;
        });
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way would be - configure [Restangular.setErrorInterceptor](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#seterrorinterceptor) in the **`.run()`** phase *(check the `Restangular` not `RestangularProvider`)*. There we can get the `$state` as expected

See also:

#### [Configuring in the run](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#configuring-in-the-run)

```
// Here I inject the service BaseUrlCalculator which I need
app.run(function(Restangular, BaseUrlCalculator) {
    Restangular.setBaseUrl(BaseUrlCalculator.calculate());
});
```